# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "hätten", "hätten sollen" und "sollten"?

Tags: conjunction, modal-verb

1. Ich hätte heute mein Handy mitgenommen.
2. Ich hätte heute mein Handy mitnehmen sollen.
3. Ich sollte heute mein Handy mitnehmen.

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen diesen drei Sätzen?

Answer (score 1):

> Ich [an deiner Stelle] hätte heute mein Handy mitgenommen.

As is, this sounds like advice to someone: "[If I was you] I would have taken my cell today."

If you don't mean it as an advice to someone, you'd mostly follow with an if clause like this:

> Ich hätte heute mein Handy mitgenommen, wenn es nicht kaputt wäre.

"I would have taken my cell if it wasn't broken." It's looking back at a situation.

> Ich hätte heute mein Handy mitnehmen sollen.

"I should have taken my cell today." This means it's too late to change things, the decision has been made, and looking back you think you should have done it differently.

> Ich sollte heute mein Handy mitnehmen.

"I should take my cell today." This is used when you still have the chance to do so, for example, when you are about to leave the house and turn back to get your cell.

Comment: Warum antwortest du auf Englisch? Nichts deutet darauf hin, dass der Fragesteller Englisch spricht. Er hat auf Deutsch gefragt, da wäre es nett in der Sprache zu antworten, von der man als einzige weiß, dass er sie spricht.

Comment: Weitere Interpretationsmöglichkeiten in indirekter Rede: 
Zu 1: Karl fragte Anna, ob ich telefonisch zu erreichen wäre. Sie hat ihm dann geantwortet, im Prinzip ja, ich hätte (jedenfalls) heute mein Handy mitgenommen.
Zu 2:  Da standen wir, ohne Benzin. Sie meinte, ich hätte heute mein Handy (besser) mitnehmen sollen. Ihrs war ja kaputt.
Zu 3:  Meine Frau hat gesagt, ich sollte heute (unbedingt) mein Handy mitnehmen, damit sie mich erreichen kann, wenn mit meiner Mutter im Krankenhaus was ist.

Answer (score 1):

> Ich hätte heute mein Handy mitgenommen.

*Ich habe das Handy nicht dabei. Irgendetwas hat mich davon abgehalten, das Handy mitzunehmen.*

> Ich hätte heute mein Handy mitnehmen sollen.

*Ich habe das Handy nicht dabei. Das wäre in der Rückschau aber empfehlenswert gewesen.*

> Ich sollte heute mein Handy mitnehmen.

*Ich habe das Handy dabei, wie man mir empfohlen hat.*

**oder**

*Ich bin noch nicht weg. Es ist empfehlenswert, das Handy mitzunehmen.*